# Win7 window becomes translucent after click and hold

Tags: windows-7, drag

This is not a programming question but I hope Microsoft programmer can see this and answer this easier.

All fine until I had a third monitor which is USB 3.0 to HDMI to DIV.  Not able to adjust the gama, so performed **A LOT OF** changes to try to achieve the goal, but only found that whenever I click a window and hold (drag or not doesn't matter), the window with its content both change to translucent (I would say 90% transparent, barely see content, but see clearly the under window).  Now Outlook and some old software (written in VC++6.0 by our team member) doesn't do this but most windows in Win 7 and new software (IE, skype, SAP, ) does this and this annoyes me.  I want non-transparent window when I drag it.  can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Microsoft expert answered that this was caused by nVidia setting.  When nVidia manager is used, all windows become translucent when clicked and held by default.